# How to setup multiple websites on single typo3 v9 installation

Tags: multisite, typo3-9.x

Any one can explain, how to setup multiple websites on the single TYPO3 installation?. TYPO3 have multisite concept. But i have searched through internet, no documentation found.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can say:

1. Edit the page you want to behavior as root page
    1.1. Check `Use as Root Page` (Tab behaviour)
2. Setup a site configuration (site configuration -> sites -> `Add new site configuration for this site`)
    2.1 Set a `Site identifier` (content dont affect the domain; its just used for the folder naming)
    2.2 Set `Entry Point` to either your domain or to `/`
    2.3 Variants can be added later and you don't need to ind about as long as you work with just one environment (production; add variants if you also got a local instance with the same code base and a live db dump)
    2.3 Switch to Languages and set your default language (maybe english)
        2.3.1 Choose an available language
        2.3.2 Set an entry point (by default the `/` should work fine for defualt but you won't get a custom language url snippet generated for `/`)
        2.3.3 Choose the available `Language ID`
        2.3.4 Choose the correct `Language Key for XLF Files`
        2.3.5 Choose the correct `Locale` (I prefer to set `UTF-8` at the end of the locale -> `en_US.UTF-8` or `de_DE.UTF-8`)
        2.3.6 Choose the correct `Two Letter ISO Code`

Now you should be fine. Just repeat this for every Domain and beginning with step 2.3.1 for every language on the domain

Comment: Thank you, for marketing reasons I need two domains for the same tree (root page the same), in the 'old' setup I'd just enter a second domain record ...

Comment: @webMan for which typo3 version?

Comment: I am programming a site with V9.5.13 (latest currently available), I copied the complete folder in sites and made a duplicate with different name/id ... that does not work

Comment: if its a lot of work I'll pose a sperate question so I can give credit for the answer, it's indeed a question on its own ...

Answer (score -1):

There's an old topic on typo3 wiki about multidomain:
https://wiki.typo3.org/Multidomain

I believe the main idea is the same:

1. Create a page. On "Behavior" tab set "Use as root page"
2. Add a domain record to this page
3. Add a template

Also I should notice there's some magic with sorting root pages so I recommend to create all root pages with the same parent

Comment: I'm sorry but the multidomain concept of TYPO3 changed extremely in implementation. This Link is outdated and can't be used for TYPO3 version 9.5.x (LTS). Even if domain records can stille xist, they aren't used as domain entry point anymore. The concept of domain records might be removed in the future. The only useful resource atm as far as i found out is the official TYPO3 documentation and they don't explain in detail how to setup a multidomain and multi language system as full system