# Multidomain multilanguage sites on single typo3 v10 installation

Tags: typo3, content-management-system, multilingual, typo3-10.x

I have read all [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/CreateNew.html) and something that seems obvious is not happening in my installation. I have several domains:

- domain.net
- domain.fr
- domain.it

all of them are pointing the typo3 folder in server. After adding all these domains and corresponding languages in site management > sites

I still only get original frontend in .net domain rest wont show anything (blank).

Note: most information online is older versions and it seems that this point has been simplified in this version, so there is no need to include any code in .htaccess or other files. Also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480063/how-to-setup-multiple-websites-on-single-typo3-v9-installation)

Looking into my folder tree I can see these folders (for each site) in mainfolder/typo3conf/sites and every of them has its config.yaml file.

Substituted real name for "domain"

this is what .net looks like (english version)

```
    base: 'https://example.net/'
baseVariants: {  }
errorHandling: {  }
languages:
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    base: 'https://example.net/'
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_US.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: English
    hreflang: en-US
    direction: ltr
    flag: en-us-gb
    languageId: '0'
rootPageId: 1
routes: {  }
websiteTitle: ''
```

This is .fr (french version)

```
base: 'http://example.fr/'
baseVariants: {  }
errorHandling: {  }
languages:
  -
    title: French
    enabled: true
    languageId: '0'
    base: 'http://example.fr/'
    typo3Language: fr
    locale: fr_FR.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: fr
    navigationTitle: Français
    hreflang: fr-fr
    direction: ltr
    flag: fr
    websiteTitle: ''
rootPageId: 2
routes: {  }
websiteTitle: ''
```

Tree inside is just this

[image]

Pages have dummy content we arent developing anymore until this problem is solved.

Any idea?

Server setup should be ok as before typo3 i was able to have a wordpress multisite and it did show content. As WP isnt native multilanguage and it works with all kind of plugins that just break everything when you update. This is why we are changing to typo3. But that is another story.

Comment: Do you really want 3 sites with separate page trees or do you actually want translated pages?
Can you add your site config .yaml (usually in folder ./config/) to the question?
And maybe a screenshot of your page tree(s)?

Comment: Mainly it would be translated pages in different domains. Let me edit to add your requests

Comment: thanks @jonaseberle, found out. Nothong related with typo3

Comment: Nice that you found your problem. Just a notice: You have different root pages for each language. It is more usual to have only one root page and page tree, but pages and content translated to different languages. That's the strength of TYPO3.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that would be ideal but we find it complicated without a .com domain available. We are willing to rank well in different countries, therefore we bought country domains. Another note just if someone reads this: WPML plugin is impossible to update on a multidomain WP installation. This is why we are moving to typo3

Comment: TYPO3 supports language domains without problems since v9 (See `base` for each language). You an map domains OR paths to a language (domain.fr -> FR or /fr/ -> FR).

Answer (score 0):

Usually when everything seems fine but it doesnt work, its something silly.

.fr domains and others were handling a lower version of php so it wouldnt run typo3

So if something like this happens to you check php version on every domain!!!